# Running Eclipse with m2eclipse (maven) from flash drive

Tags: eclipse, maven

Hello I am trying to run my Eclipse + Maven from a flash drive. Basically, I am able to load my eclipse and JDK from the flash drive. My eclipse is using m2eclipse plugin (Embedded versions 3.0.2)

Eclipse and Java projects works fine except for Maven, which I have set the repository path relative to the eclipse path i.e:

> ./m2repo

And also pointed settings.xml to a relative location `./settings.xml:`

> Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations

I have working maven projects which I opened in my "portable" Eclipse that was executed from flash drive, which did get some errors:

> Execution default-resources of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3

What could be the reason why I'm getting this error?

Comment: The single line you posted in the end doesn't look like a error to me, please post more Maven output to show what is the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me to use absolute path

Comment: settings.xml and the repository path. @xybrek